# How to determine path in svn-repository that was committed to

Tags: svn

For a post-commit hookscript on my windows server I want to determine what the highest path into the repository was that the commit was started on.

So, if I have a working copy based on repository path `product\branch\somebranch` and a commit is done from that working copy of changed files and folders, how can i trace it back to `product\branch\somebranch` in the post-commit script?

Preferably I am looking for a method that is not dependent on the structure of my repo to avoid having to explicitly code out differences between commit into the trunk and branches i.e.

Answer (score 0):

The post-commit hook receives 2 arguments: the full path to the local on-disk repository and the revision number that was committed.

Assuming your host is running on a unix machine you can use these parameters together with 'svnlook' in the post-commit script to find the path in the repository. This will give you the full path of the changes in the repository.

```
#!/bin/sh
REPOS="$1"
REV="$2"
svnlook changed -r$REV "$REPOS"
```

svnlook output is like this:

```
A   product/branches/somebranch/Makefile
U   product/branches/somebranch/main.c
```

from there you can extract the highest path piping through cut a couple of times to strip off the modified flags and parse the path e.g.

```
svnlook changed -r$REV "$REPOS" | cut -c5- | cut -d/ -f1-3
```

This part really depends on your repo layout, and there are many approaches you could take but this should get you started.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. (Not using Linux here, but that doesnt matter). I was hoping for a method that would not be dependent on my Repo-layout, to avoid have to handle i.e. differences between branches and trunk commits.

Comment: Well, yes. Subversion is just what you make of it really regarding directories. For example, where I work we don't use "trunk" - everything is in project/branches/ and the trunk branch, where main development happens, is just a branch called "project/branches/main". Using the trunk convention just added exception cases in our hooks for little gain, so we ditched it.